# Call a NodeJS RestAPI from Flutter using Localhost

Tags: flutter, networking

I running nodeJS server on my mac and have some API services. I connected my iPhone to my mac. How can I can make my app call the API services that is running on localhost

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone and the Mac are connected to your local network. They both have local IP addresses. In your app, you need to connect to your Mac's IP address like `https://192.168.0.3/some.js`. If your Mac does not have some Firewall to block this, it should work.